# Convert existing rails cucumber capybara test stack to use headless gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber, capybara, xvfb

I have an existing rails app with cucumber/capybara automated tests that run inside xvfb. I'd like to use the headless gem to get video capture of these tests but I don't know where to insert the headless.ly blocks so that it hooks ALL driver requests. Is there a single place in rails where I can do this? Or would it require more extensive changes?

https://github.com/leonid-shevtsov/headless